# testing cakephp restful api callback

Tags: cakephp

I have followed the cakephp documentation for 2.0 to create a restFUL. I am not sure if I have it right.

If I was to just put the URL into the browser should I see the xml called back. I am just trying to test it but all I see is the standard view and not the xml view. I just want a quick test to see if I have it right.

The URL

http://www.mydomain.com/members/123.xml
The controller is Members and the method I am calling is view

Here is my code:

routes.php

```
Router::mapResources('members');
Router::parseExtensions('xml', 'json');
```

MembersController.php

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Member->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid member'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Member.' . $this->Member->primaryKey => $id));
    $members = $this->Member->find('first', $options);
    $this->set(array(
        'member' => $members,
        '_serialize' => array('member')
    ));
}
```

app/view/members/xml/view.ctp

```
echo $xml->serialize($member)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you the RequestHandler in your components array? If not put it in there.

See [this page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) in the CakePHP book.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have a problem with the docs, the restFUL section never mentioned this or pointed to this view article. I find this a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any view, CakePHP handles it automatically. Delete folder app/view/members/ with all files inside.

Comment: not sure if it does this in version 2.0. It still looks for a view